# On a web page how do I display a label that changes to a drop down box on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to see a label on the screen that when the mouse pointer hovers over it is changed to a dropdown list.

I have the following

```
<div class="sizeit"> 
    <select id="SelectUrgency" class="invisible">
        <option value="3">Non Urgent</option>
        <option value="2">Urgent</option>
        <option value="1">System Down</option>
    </select>
    <label>test</label>
<div>
```

With the following css

```
.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    position: static;
}
.sizeit {
    width: 100px;
    height: 440px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and the following javascript

```
$("div").hover(  function () {    $(this).find("label:first").remove();  },  
              function () {    $(this).append($("<label>test</label>"));  });

$("div.sizeit").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find("select:first").addClass("visible");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find("select:first").removeClass("visible");    
        $(this).find("select:first").addClass("invisible"); 
    });
```

This almost works but when the dropdown box is clicked on I cant select a item. Does anyone know how this can be fixed so the dropdown box item can be selected?

Comment: I'm not sure if this happens here. I encountered a problem when things weren't working if they were hidden at the beginning. Try to load it without this hidden class and then add a function to your body onload to set the class for your hidden box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aKh5x/

HTML:

```
<div class="sizeit"> 
<select id="SelectUrgency" class="invisible">
    <option value="3">Non Urgent</option>
    <option value="2">Urgent</option>
    <option value="1">System Down</option>
</select>
<label>test</label>
```

CSS:

```
.sizeit > select {
    display:none;
}
.sizeit > label {
    display:block;
}
.sizeit > select:focus, .sizeit:hover > select {
    display:block;
}
.sizeit > select:focus + label, .sizeit:hover > label {
    display:none;
}
```

:focus rule will prevent selectbox from disappearing.

hope this is good solution for you

Comment: Thanks for that it does just what I asked for. But supposing when the user selects a item from the drop down, how would I make it so the dropdown become invisble and the label returns updated with the selected item?

Comment: try something like $(".sizeit > select").change(function(){text = $(this).val();$(this).parent().find('label').text(text);});

Comment: Thanks again for that. I changed it slightly to $(".sizeit > select").change(function()
                             {
                                 text = $(this).find("[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").text()
                                 $(this).parent().find('label').text(text);
                             });